# How to add class when you're placed in a section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I've made my website and I'm trying to give it some style. I have the following code to change class.
It makes the navigation background appear if you scrolled 600pixels or more.

```
<script>
        $(document).scroll(function() {
            if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 600) {
                $('.navbar-default').addClass('sticky');
            } else {
                $('.navbar-default').removeClass('sticky');
            }
        });
</script>
```

My question is, is there any way to add or remove classes besides the scroll function?

I was thinking something like: "If I'm in div with id #example, then add class .sticky", because I don't know how many pixels the div will have if you are watching it in your phone or tablet.

Website:
[googledrive.com/host/0B7F-fUHZZLadcE1QRXhUNnp5enM](http://googledrive.com/host/0B7F-fUHZZLadcE1QRXhUNnp5enM)

Edit: Any tutorial on how to send contact forms using ajax?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the offset.top value of the element you want to use as the check point. For example, your script could be something like this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $("#example").offset().top) {
        $('.navbar-default').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('.navbar-default').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the height of the header on your current device and then add the class as soon as you have reached that scroll point.

```
<script>
    $(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $('#headerwrapper').css('height')) {
        $('.navbar-default').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.navbar-default').removeClass('sticky');
        }
    });
</script>
```

An alternate solution would be to calculate the viewport of the screen and check wether a div is inside the current position by using the X & Y coordinates but this seems overly complicated.